# checking condition loop with scanner

Tags: conditional-statements, java.util.scanner

I am trying to write a code that will loop you in case you provide wrong data. The problem is that I need to have some type of "Bad data" message for both 2 cases:
- you enter not an integer value
- you enter the value below 0

In this code if you type a letter, it loops you with a message: "Bad data", but if you type for example negative value like -10 Bad data is not appearing (even though validation works and you need to correct number to positive)

How can I do it more universal, so in both scenarios sysout with print on-screen Bad data

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    int los = rand.nextInt(11);
    int NumberOfPlayers ;

    Scanner scan7 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(" Type number of players :");

    do {
        while (!scan7.hasNextInt()){
            System.out.println(" Bad data");
            scan7.next();
        }
        NumberOfPlayers = scan7.nextInt();
    }while (NumberOfPlayers < 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are only validating if scanner has next int, you do not validate it's value, and integers can be negative.
try this solution:

```
    do {
        while (!scan7.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println(" Bad data");
            scan7.next();
        }
        NumberOfPlayers = scan7.nextInt();
        if (NumberOfPlayers <= 0) {
            System.out.println(" Number must be larger than zero");
        }
    } while (NumberOfPlayers <= 0);
```

After checking for next int, I added part checking value of provided int.

ALSO please remember about naming variables and classes - start with small letter, so in your case `NumberOfPlayers`  should be `numberOfPlayers`.
Why you named scanner `scan7`? is there valid reason for that name? if no, you should avoid adding numbers to names.

Comment: ALmost works but I get such result: Bad data
-14
 Number must be larger than zero
-14
-14
 Number must be larger than zero

Comment: it means that first time I type negative number it prints: number must be larger then zero, second time I type negative value I need to do it 2 times to get to the prompt message

Comment: sorry, check my edited code - now I am after my first coffee - this one works for sure :)

Comment: after checking if next value from scanner is integer, we assign it to variable, and then we do validation on that variable, and display message if needed. clean, simple, working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207743/discussion-between-lukas-novicky-and-tomek-mlynarski).